# Changing the icon image on routing in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I want to change an image after going to /tab1. This can be done by 'ng-click'. But need to be done using AngularJS routing.

Html file:

```
<div class = "body" ng-controller = "app">
    <div class = "column1">
        <div class = "tab1">
            <a href = "#/tab1"><img ng-src="{{ imageUrl }}"></a>
        </div>
```

Controller.js :

```
var application = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']);

application.controller('app', function($scope) {
    console.log("Executed");
    $scope.imageUrl = 'profile-icon.png';
});

application.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/tab1', {templateUrl: 'tab1.html', controller: HomeCtrl}).
            when('/tab2', {templateUrl: 'tab2.html'}).
            when('/tab3', {templateUrl: 'tab3.html'}).
            otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);

function HomeCtrl($scope) {
    console.log("Inside ToggleImage");
    $scope.imageUrl = 'profile-icon-clicked.png';
}
```

Page successfully loading the 'profile-icon.png'. But after clicking image is not changing. But I can see the output 'Inside ToggleImage' in browser console.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And `imageUrl` are in different scope in two controllers. If you want them to be same every where use `$rootscope` not `$scope`

Comment: It's the full code of HomeCtrl .Your logic seems right.

Comment: I had to replace the $scope to $rootScope. Now it's working as intended. But the 'HomeCtrl' thing you mentioned is not correct. I suggest you to edit your answer. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

That's because you modify property of child scope, not parent scope. See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes for explanations on scope inheritance.

The easiest way to solve this is to have an object on a parent scope.

```
var application = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']);

application.controller('app', function($scope) {
    console.log("Executed");
    $scope.settings= {imageUrl: 'profile-icon.png'};
});

application.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/tab1', {templateUrl: 'tab1.html', controller: HomeCtrl}).
            when('/tab2', {templateUrl: 'tab2.html'}).
            when('/tab3', {templateUrl: 'tab3.html'}).
            otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);

function HomeCtrl($scope) {
    console.log("Inside ToggleImage");
    $scope.settings.imageUrl = 'profile-icon-clicked.png';
}
```

Comment: Do I have to go that far? I chaged $scope to $scope.settings , but didn't work for me. Since I'm changing my variable in two different functions $rootScope should be used instead of $scope.